# Google Chrome Flicker

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Hi guys I am new here and not a coder but rather a manager for our upocoming project to be released in the summer of 2017.

My developers and coders could not find what is the cause of the flicker that exists on Chrome alone for our website at [www.playinera.com](http://www.playinera.com)

I am well aware that this is a Chrome issue and well documented bug. After searching for weeks on various sites, including stackoverflow, we were not able to pinpoint its cause.

If anyone has experience with this flickering issue and would like to take a stab at it, that would be greatly appreciated. I really can't post any snippets of code because we don't know where the issue lies.

Willing to give access to any tools or credentials you may need and can spare time to go over any details in private.

Comment: how to reproduce your issue? I'm using `Chrome/56.0.2924.110` (chromebook)

Comment: I'm not seeing any flickering on Chrome 57.0.2965.0 canary on an Acer C720 Chromebook.

Comment: Yea, we think we finally located it. Cloudflare issue likely that is causing this sorry guys thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

We also faced the same issue. Our application was working fine until Chrome got updated [Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)].

We checked our application in other browsers like firefox and explorer. The application was running fine. So it was confirmed that this flickering issue was not a bug from our end.

Going through different blogs, I encountered that we need to disable hardware acceleration under Settings > Advanced > Uncheck - Use hardware acceleration when available and relaunch the browser to save the settings.

It worked for us.

Comment: This worked for me. When I upgraded the chrome version, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Changing personalization settings doesn't work for Chrome flickering in some cases.

Just go to the Chrome settings, search for

```
Use hardware acceleration when available
```

uncheck it and relaunch Chrome.