# Gatsby Image Chrome flicker on Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, windows, google-chrome, gatsby

I have a React Gatsby web app and I have a component that renders answer cards with an image on each card. I know there is a known issue with windows 10 and chrome which is fixed by disabling hardware acceleration, but my site is the only one that I have such bad flickering. I have tried to refactor everything to have the best performance but the issue persists.

[image]

I know that this [Google Chrome Flicker Unable to Find Cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017755/google-chrome-flicker-unable-to-find-cause/46580168)
solves the issue, but users will not do this since even for me this is the only site that this happens.

My components look something like this.

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center py-10 px-8">
  {answers.map((e) => (
    <Field key={e.id} type="radio" name={id} value={e.answerId}>
      {() => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={onClick}
            className="flex flex-col justify-around w-32 h-44 2k:w-48 2k:h-72 shadow-3xl rounded-md mx-2 my-3 cursor-pointer transform transition-transform"
          >
            <div className="flex-1" />
            <div className="inline-block px-2 m-3">
              <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/247/929/png-transparent-potato-food-anime-potato-food-manga-cartoon.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
         );
      }}
    </Field>
  ))}
</div>
```

I have tried almost everything. Removing flex does not fix the issue. If I remove the image the issue is fixed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Although in general the flickering issue with Chrome + Windows is fixed, it seems that there are cases where hardware acceleration is still struggling.

In my case I had a div element with filter grayscale CSS and both box-shadow applied (for the card unselected state above). Probably chrome renderer had issues applying the filter to the box-shadow element so that caused the flickering. I moved the filter to the inside image element (which makes more sense either way) and the issue was fixed.